# How to invoke gsutil or use path of GCS objects to move data from GCS to s3 bucket using cloud function

Tags: python, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to move files from GCS to s3 bucket using GC Functions (equivalent of AWS Lambda). To achieve it, I've tried 3 different methods. In method 1  I get error  and while I do not get error in other 2 options, the files actually don't get copied over.

Can someone please help ?

The two other methods are marked with # and I have tried each one separately.

s3_client.upload_file is not working because it expects a path of the source file and when i provide 'gs://< google_bucket_name>/30327570.pdf', it say

'No such file or directory exists'

gustil command executes correctly without error but no new file gets created in the s3 bucket.

```
import os
from google.cloud import storage
import boto3
import subprocess

s3_client=boto3.client('s3',aws_access_key_id='XYZ',aws_secret_access_key='ABC')
client = storage.Client()
def hello_gcs(data, context):
    bucket = client.get_bucket(data['bucket'])
    blob = bucket.blob(data['name'])
   #subprocess.call(['gsutil -m rsync -r gs://<google_bucket_name>/30327570.pdf s3://<aws_bucket_name>'], shell=True)
    subprocess.call(['gsutil cp gs://<google_bucket_name>/30327570.pdf s3://<aws_bucket_name>'], shell=True)
   #s3_client.upload_file('gs://<google_bucket_name>/30327570.pdf','<aws_bucket_name>','30327570.pdf')
```

Answer (score 0):

if [gsutil rsync](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync) won't work, you can try with [rclone](https://rclone.org/), or invert the process to [migrate data from S3 to GCS](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/migrating).

Answer (score 0):

Although this is written in JavaScript, here is a Google Cloud Function to sync files from a GCS bucket to an S3 bucket:

https://github.com/pendo-io/gcs-s3-sync